# Cancel background backup operation on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

How can one cleanly cancel a background backup operation on Windows Server 2008 created through the Windows Server Backup console using Backup Once after the status windows has been closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.

C:\> wbadmin stop job

Comment: I would note: 1) this requires elevated privileges (i.e., *Run as Administrator...*) 2) It can still take a long time to abort (20+ mins).  Searching the internet one may find those who are impatient and end up manually stopping the **Block Level Backup Engine** service or kill its associated process.  I wouldn't recommend the latter; better to be patient and let `wbadmin stop job` do its job.